# Is any reason to put @NotNull annotation on @Id field in Java entity class

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

I found code in entity class:

```
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Is **@NotNull** annotation have value when **@Id** already set?

Comment: If you're using a database autoincremented value or sequence then you shouldn't use the `@NotNull` annotation. It would throw an exception when you try to persist the entity.

Comment: Hm... I simplify code, but original one have `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue` and there are no any errors in runtime on inserts... Seems that different libraries and versions behave differently. Thanks for interest. +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@NotNull` is for validation purposes, like `@Size`.  It defines rules for a validation engine to check whether user input is ok.  Doing validation around these annotation doesn't necessarily indicate that the object is also a JPA object but the two are often used together.

If you're using javax.validation instead of relying on failure at the DB level (constraint violations) to indicate null values, then you should use both annotations.

Comment: Thanks +1. Most direct answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The UI layer for example may require @NotNull attributes. Validation is a cross-cutting concern, so you expect it to show up in many places throughout the application.

Answer (score 2):

`@Id` is used to

```
 * Specifies the primary key of an entity.
 * The field or property to which the <code>Id</code> annotation is applied
 * should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type;
 * any primitive wrapper type;
 * <code>String</code>;
 * <code>java.util.Date</code>;
 * <code>java.sql.Date</code>;
 * <code>java.math.BigDecimal</code>;
 * <code>java.math.BigInteger</code>.
```

So it doesn't takes care of null values. To prevent null values `@NotNull` is used along with `@Id`.

Comment: Thanks. +1. I read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html and  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html but this doesn't help me in understanding...

Comment: Allowing a null primary key would be a violation of the SQL spec.

Answer (score 1):

Since `id / primary key` is the most important [field](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/hibernate_id_annotation.shtml) in the table, it `uniquely` identify a row in the table.

So it shouldn't be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will make your id field not nullable and you have to give it mandatory.

But if you want id to autoincrement then remove it and add

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this is for static analysis and has nothign to do with hibernate/orm. Is it the intellij specific annotation ?

So at compile time you can be warned when you are about to assign NULL to a field that has been annotated as @NotNull.

And any code that is dependent knows that the returned value will never be null.

Comment: It's from JSR303 (Bean Validation), which is like JPA also just part of Java EE.